# Can't use members of array of structures C#

Tags: c#, .net

Good morning everyone, I've a problem with the members of the array to which I can't use inside a function even when I declared the structure as global. The detail is that like I wanna read some values entered by console, store them in the array of structures an then read them an print them again in console but I can't use the members inside the functions, Visual Studio 2013 community gives me the following error: Error 1   The name 'Students' does not exist in the current context.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Practica_modulo_4
{
    class Program
    {
        public struct student                                                               //Structure to hold the data of a student.
        {
            private string firstName, lastName, degree;                                     //Declaration of members of the structure.
            private DateTime birthDay;

            public string FirstName                                                         //Property of access to firstName.
            {
                get
                {
                    return firstName;
                }
                set
                {
                    firstName = value;
                }
            }

            public string LastName                                                          //Property of access to lastName.
            {
                get
                {
                    return lastName;
                }
                set
                {
                    lastName = value;
                }
            }
            public DateTime BirthDay                                                        //Property of access to birthday.
            {
                get
                {
                    return birthDay;
                }
                set
                {
                    birthDay = value;
                }
            }
            public string Degree                                                            //Property of access to degree.
            {
                get
                {
                    return degree;
                }
                set
                {
                    degree = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public static void readstudenData();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            student[] Students = new student[5];
            readstudentData();                                                              //Reading of one student's information.
            printstudentData(Students[0].FirstName, Students[0].LastName, Students[0].BirthDay, Students[0].Degree);//Printing of
            //the information read at readstudentData().
        }


        public static void readstudentData()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Please type the first name, last name, birthday (YYYY,DD,MM) and degree to obtain for the student\npressing Enter each time:");
            Students[0].FirstName = Console.ReadLine();                                     //Reading of the elements for the first student,
            Students[0].LastName = Console.ReadLine();                                      //note that I've used this form because of the
            Students[0].BirthDay = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());                  //instructions for the assignment, there are better
            Students[0].Degree = Console.ReadLine();                                        //ways to do the assignment for all de elements of the
                                                                                            //array but the text of the assignment explicitly says
                                                                                            //to not to publish that information because is part
                                                                                            //of the challenge, so please don't penalize me for
                                                                                            //this.
        }

        static void printstudentData(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime birthday, string degree)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("El estudiante {0} {1} nació el {2} y el grado que obtendrá es: {3}",firstName,lastName,Convert.ToString(birthday),degree);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

}

Comment: Students is a local variable inside main. So is out of scope in readstudentData.

Comment: isn't this a problem from an edx course?

Answer (score 8):

This is because you have declared it inside the scope of another function, which makes it a `local` variable.

Declare that variable outside your all functions to make it `global` so that you can use it inside the other functions as well.

Hope this clears it.

Comment: Mark it as answer for other's references and more to come.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move`student[] Students = new student[5];` outside of Main and declare as `static`

Comment: Don't forget to mark whichever response solved your issue as the answer.